# Add multi-tenancy bean scope in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi tenant Spring MVC application. There are `Service`s that cache data based on the current tenant. I have a mechanism that is able to tell me the tenant for the current request (based on the user authentication token). **My question is how I can introduce a new `scope` in Spring MVC that is selected based on the current tenant.**

The idea is as follows. In the configuration, some beans have `tenant` specified as the scope. When a request is authenticated the tenant is known. Based on this tenant I want to select something (a `BeanFactory`?) that holds the service instances specific to that tenant so that resolving a bean/service in the context of that request return the tenant specific services.

Comment: Have you take a look at `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer` you can define it like that : `<bean id="scopeConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
 <property name="scopes">
  <map>
   <entry key="tenant" >
    <bean class="my.pkg.TenantScope" />
   </entry>
  </map>
 </property>
</bean>` Then in the Tenant Scope you can do your multi-tenant logic.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to check this out.